# Can I create a generic method in c# that accepts a type based on whether it contains a certain method or not?

Tags: c#

I want to create a generic method that takes any class that implements a certain method, for example Print(), usually in such a case we need a common interface and then I would say something like : `where T : ICustomInterface` and the compiler would guarantee that type T contains any methods in that interface. However, in cases where I do not have access to the type, for example I can not modify the List class part of the System.Collections.Generic namespace to implement my interface, can you still achieve this functionality?

Comment: As far as I know, no. The way around that is to do the work at runtime, using Reflection.

Comment: Any more information you can share about specifics of what you are trying to accomplish? We might be able to find a different solution that isn't obvious from the question you're asking

Comment: @Flydog57: List<T> is not sealed (only very few classes are. String is the only I can think off). So just inherit it, adding constraints to the T parameter. You can usually make a generic more specific.

Comment: @Prescott I wanted to create a generic class that takes anything that implements an indexer, and then have a generic "Peek" method (look forward in a list, array, or anything that contains an indexer) based on the current state of this class etc.

Comment: @fYre In C#, every class can be given a Indexer. So I doubt you can use constraints here. Honestly, I can not think of anything but reflection here.

Comment: C# uses [Nominal type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), but not [Structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system). So the answer is no, you can't do it directly.

Comment: @fYre I realized something: While you can not check for indexers, you can definie indedexers in a Interface. | The only other way would be Reflection. I try to avoid using Reflection. It is a fallback that should be avoided. But in this case a check for the existence of Indexers and a throw of a ArgumentException could work. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> However, in cases where I do not have access to the type, for example I can not modify the List class part of the System.Collections.Generic namespace to implement my interface, can you still achieve this functionality?

Try this first:

```
public class customList<T> : List<T> where T : ICustomInterface{

}
```

According to SharpLab, [it valid code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4qkDchhGAzOVqQMKkDehpP5TGVALIAKAJSduvAL6EZBQgHoFASVIBXAM4wAJqWUAZAJYaALgB4AKgD4ANKQCGGvaQB2MHTocuAnl92GTUgB3R1JDF1INSAAHGHp+FjBNEwgAWyNTSytSEFIM82tggAsYWFILHL18rK55AikgA===). But you need proper compiler confirmation.

If it does not work, there is the MVVM way: "If you can not modify it, wrap it into something you *can* modify." Just put a `List<T>` inside of a custom class as private field and add all the List Functions you want, by simply relaying thhe cals it to the `List<T>` inside.

Edit:

> I wanted to create a generic class that takes anything that implements an indexer, and then have a generic "Peek" method (look forward in a list, array, or anything that contains an indexer) based on the current state of this class etc

Unfortunately, "having a Indexer" is not something Generics can test. In .NET [every class can be given a Indexer,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) as much as it can be given Functions, Fields and Properties.

Reflection can [Identify Indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters). I only ever consider Reflection as a fallback, but it is one way.

Despite the checking limits of generics, you can define [Indexers in a Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/indexers-in-interfaces), as much as you could Functions and Properties. At the end of the day, Indexers are propably mostly Syntax sugar for Function calls like properties are. While doing so would at a first glance exclude the Build-in List types, it is easy enough to sublcass them and have them implement the Interface.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to add an interface this is going to be pretty hard to accomplish is a type friendly manner. I don't know the usefulness of this, but it could be done:

```
public void Print(object myObj) {
    var method = myObj.GetType().GetMethod("Print");
    if (method != null) method.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can’t do what you’re asking exactly. But you could write a wrapper class that allows you to set a delegate for the required method, and use the wrapper in the type constraint.

```
class Printable
{
    protected readonly Action _action;

    public Printable(Action printAction)
    {
        _action = printAction;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        _action();
    }
}

void CallPrint<T>(T obj) where T : Printable
{
    obj.Print();
}

var wrapper = new Printable( ()=> foo.Print() );
CallPrint(wrapper)(
```

You could do a similar thing for classes that have indexers, although you would use a Func instead of an Action.